# How to get all values of every combobox from my DataGridView and Add them to DataTable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, datatable

I added a ComboBox to my DataGridView

```
DBAccess dba = new DBAccess();
DataTable dt = dba.spGetASTMTable(); // Getting Data from DataBase for Grid
DataTable dtOrders = dba.spGetOrdersList(); / Getting Data from DataBase for ComboBox
// Create ComboBox
var cboDbTableColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cboDbTableColumn.DataSource = dtOrders;
cboDbTableColumn.DataPropertyName = "OrdersID";
cboDbTableColumn.DisplayMember = "Orders";
cboDbTableColumn.HeaderText = "DbTableColumn";

gvASTMOrderMessage.Columns.Add(cboDbTableColumn);

gvASTMOrderMessage.DataSource = dt;
```

Then I run my app and change couple ComboBoxes.
I Click button "Save" and I want to get DataTable with all DataGridView Data. As I understand, because of my ComboBox is on a part of DataSource then I need to loop through whole Grid and manually add values of ComboBox to my DataTable. I'm trying to do this step here:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataTable data = (DataTable)(gvASTMOrderMessage.DataSource);
     data.Columns.Add("DbTableColumn");
     for (int i = 0; i < gvASTMOrderMessage.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         data.Rows[i]["DbTableColumn"] = Convert.ToString((gvASTMOrderMessage.Rows[i].Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).FormattedValue.ToString());
     }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I've tried to get

```
gvASTMOrderMessage.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString()
gvASTMOrderMessage.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()
gvASTMOrderMessage.Rows[i].Cells[0].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()
```

But nothing of this works...

Help please, how to get all values of every combobox from my DataGridView and Add them to DataTable?

Comment: Why don't you add "DbTableColumn" to your datasource dt DataTable?

Comment: @xeondev DbTableColumn is of type DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. If you could add it to the datasource (by using some kind of "trick" as what I proposed), the DataGridView wouldn't show the right information anyway. You have to add these kind of special column types "manually" to the DataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataSource` and `DataGridView` are two different objects which are somehow coordinated. But this coordination is not perfect and, actually, can easily drive to problems (deleting elements from the `DataSource` and accessing those indices from the `DataGridView`). That's why, I always prefer to affect both objects at the same time (`DataSource` and `DataGridView`).

In any case, bear in mind that quite a few changes you perform in the `DataGridView` (e.g., adding/removing columns) are not automatically reflected in the `DataSource` (although it can happen inversely). In your specific situation, this behaviour makes still more sense as far as automating the inclusion of a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` type column into a `DataSource` (perhaps a `DataTable`, perhaps other object) would be virtually impossible (many alternatives, no one objectively better than the others).

You should come up with a way to fit the comboboxes into your `DataTable` (for example: populate in the given column as many rows as items in the combobox and "mark" this column in some way) and implement a code performing the corresponding updating actions when required.

Comment: @Bryuk quicker, short-code ways there are quite a few. But accurate-enough ways not so many. DataGridView is a complex control which can deliver excellent results but which needs to be treated "carefully", because otherwise errors might appear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should check the

```
DataTable data = (DataTable)(gvASTMOrderMessage.DataSource);
```

check if the datatable is null (mine was). The rest of the code seems ok, also 
check

> data.Rows[i]["DbTableColumn"] = Convert.ToString((gvASTMOrderMessage.Rows[i].Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).FormattedValue.ToString());
>        }

i would do something like

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                data.Rows[i]["DbTableColumn"] = cell.FormattedValue.ToString());
```

which is a more readable version.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand something but look the following code:
I have added the extra "ComboID" column, and after you have selected items in the gridview and clicked the "Save" button the datatable will contain the IDs from the combo.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt.Columns.Add("Value");
        dt.Columns.Add("ComboID");

        var drow = dt.NewRow();
        drow[0] = 10;
        drow[1] = "abc";
        dt.Rows.Add(drow);

        drow = dt.NewRow();
        drow[0] = 20;
        drow[1] = "xy";
        dt.Rows.Add(drow);

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { DataPropertyName = "Id" });
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { DataPropertyName = "Value" });

        var dtOrders = new DataTable();
        dtOrders.Columns.Add("OrdersID");
        dtOrders.Columns.Add("Orders");

        drow = dtOrders.NewRow();
        drow[0] = 1;
        drow[1] = "Order1";
        dtOrders.Rows.Add(drow);

        drow = dtOrders.NewRow();
        drow[0] = 2;
        drow[1] = "Order2";
        dtOrders.Rows.Add(drow);

        var combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        combo.DataSource = dtOrders;
        combo.DataPropertyName = "ComboID";
        combo.ValueMember = "OrdersID";
        combo.DisplayMember = "Orders";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
    }
```